# How to exclude password protected posts in WordPress loop

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type that supports password protected entries. In a custom loop using a new WP_Query object, I want to exclude those password protected posts from the results. What arguments do I need set in order to do this? I am using the latest trunk version of WordPress 3.2.1.

Comment: Since WordPress 3.9 there is also a `has_password` query arg that you can use.

Answer (score 26):

I come up to this question where I was looking for the same. However, I read WP_Query document line by line then found very simple solution and that is just to add `'has_password' => false` argument to the query `$args`

So the code will be as below...

```
$args  = [
    'post_type'      => [ 'post', 'page' ],
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post__not_in'   => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'has_password'   => FALSE
];
```

Here you can see I have excluded `Sticky` and `Password Protected` posts.

Comment: All answers that suggest the use of SQL are dangerous and should not be used as of WordPress 3.9+. This is the built in way of excluding password protected posts.

Comment: Yes! This is the way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

I really like Kevin's approach, but I adjusted it slightly:

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function my_password_post_filter( $where = '' ) {
    // Make sure this only applies to loops / feeds on the frontend
    if (!is_single() && !is_admin()) {
        // exclude password protected
        $where .= " AND post_password = ''";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_password_post_filter' );
```

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Chester, I also added this exclusion for the `Next Post` and `Previous Post` links (see my answer).

Comment: Any idea how to apply this to pass protected posts in custom loops on a single?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Peter Chester's answer:

You may also want to exclude password-protected posts from the `Previous Post` and `Next Post` links, if you have those at the bottom of your post page.

To do so you can add the exclusion to the `get_previous_post_where` and `get_next_post_where` hooks.

```
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_where', 'my_theme_mod_adjacent' );
add_filter( 'get_next_post_where', 'my_theme_mod_adjacent' );
function my_theme_mod_adjacent( $where ) {
    return $where . " AND p.post_password = ''";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [post_status argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters) of WP_Query?

"Protected" seems like a good candidate to exclude.

***Edit:*** Okay, it seems like you'll have to modify the where clause to achieve what you want:

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // exclude password protected
    $where .= " AND post_password = ''";
    return $where;
}

if (!is_single()) { add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); }
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Comment: Yes I did see that, but it seems as if that argument is permissive of post status i.e. post_status=protected will include all protected statuses, unless I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: Just speculating, but have you tried post_status=-protected ?

Comment: The `post_where` filter is the way to go.

Comment: close but not quite ;-). there where should be post_password = '' but this where applies to viewing single entries, so while it does exclude them from archive templates etc. it also renders a 404 when trying to access a single page.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry for yet another comment, but I'm unable to do any testing of my own right now … Does wrapping the `add_filter()` statement in a `if (!is_single())` help the 404 issue?

Comment: Yep, that certainly does work, although it does seem a bit of a hack if we can't do it as an argument of WP_Query. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing about, I found the posts_where filter a bit too intrusive for what I wanted to do, so I came up with an alternative. As part of the 'save_post' action that I attached for my custom post type, I added the following logic;

```
$visibility = isset($_POST['visibility']) ? $_POST['visibility'] : '';
$protected  = get_option('__protected_posts', array());

if ($visibility === 'password' && !in_array($post->ID, $protected)) {
    array_push($protected, $post->ID);
}
if ($visibility === 'public' && in_array($post->ID, $protected)) {
    $i = array_search($post->ID, $protected);
    unset($protected[$i]);
}
update_option('__protected_posts', $protected);
```

What this does is hold an array of post id's in the options table where the post is protected by a password. Then in a custom query I simply passed this array as part of the `post__not_in` option e.g.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'post__not_in' => get_option('__protected_posts'),
));
```

This way I could exclude the protected posts from an archive page but still allow a user to land on the password protected page to enter the password.

Comment: this worked for me where the "better" solution below did not. i was using get_posts so this was really the simplest way to get the job done.